# How to prevent default sorting of children nodes in d3.layout.partition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchical-trees

d3.layout.partition automatically sorts children nodes in descending order by default. I'm using an icicle plot to show a binary tree where I want to keep the original tree structure without any node reordering. How do I create an array of nodes from my tree without the sort? 
My code sets the nodes as follows:

```
 var partition = d3.layout.partition()
.size([width, height])
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
 var nodes= partition.nodes(root);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API, when using `partition.sort([comparator])`:

> A null comparator disables sorting and uses tree traversal order.

Thus, it should be:

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([width, height])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .sort(null);
```